NextJs app throws UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT in Container
Couple of hours ago Nextjs app in Docker container stopped funtioning normally.
I looked at container's logs using docker logs and noticed the error below:
 ⨯ TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async fetchExternalImage (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/image-optimizer.js:565:17)
    at async NextNodeServer.imageOptimizer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:650:48)
    at async cacheEntry.imageResponseCache.get.incrementalCache (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:182:65)
    at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:90:36
    at async /app/node_modules/next/dist/lib/batcher.js:45:32 {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7760:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7716:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7748:13)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)
      at process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:128:17) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}

Note that container was up almost 2 weeks and had no issue.
I tried to restart Container, and it does not helped, then restarted NGINx. Updated OS itself (Ubuntu) and restarted, but that doesn't helped either.

We are experiencing the same behavior. Have you found a solution?

That's the buggy Image component issue. Remove "on error to show another image" functionality of Next Image component in your project.
